# Solve the equation $y^{\prime\prime}+4y=\frac{2}{\sin(2x)}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the equation $y^{\prime\prime}+4y=\frac{2}{\sin(2x)}$

I can find the complementary solution $y_c=c_1(\cos(2x))+c_2(\sin(2x))$

But I'm having problems finding the particular solution.

I want to choose something $A\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$ I believe.

Comment: See http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/VariationofParameters.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y^{\prime\prime}+4y=\frac{2}{\sin(2x)}\tag 1$$
A particular solution of the associated homogeneous equation is : $y=c \sin(2x)$.

Change of function (The constant $c$ is replaced by an unknown function $u(x)$ :
$$y=u(x)\sin(2x)$$
$y'=u'\sin(2x)+2u\cos(2x)$

$y''= u''\sin(2x)+4u'\cos(2x)-4u\sin(2x)$

Equation $(1)$ is transformed into
$$u''\sin(2x)+4u'\cos(2x)=\frac{2}{\sin(2x)}$$
Let $u'(x)=v(x)$
$$v'(x)\sin(2x)+4v(x)\cos(2x)=\frac{2}{\sin(2x)}$$
This is a linear first order ODE. You certainly can continue.

Answer (score 0):

By general formula the particular solution of the equation
$$
y''+q(x)y'+r(x)y=g(x)
$$
given the solutions $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ of the associated homogeneous equation
$$
y''+q(x)y'+r(x)y=0
$$
can be written as:
$$
u(x)=-y_1(x)\int\frac{y_2(x)g(x)}{W(y_1,y_2)}dx
+y_2(x)\int\frac{y_1(x)g(x)}{W(y_1,y_2)}dx,
$$
where $W(y_1,y_2)=|y_1y_2'-y_1'y_2|$ is the Wronskian of the general solutions.

In your case 
$$W(\cos2x,\sin2x)=2.$$

Thus:
$$\begin{align}
u(x)&=-\cos2x\int\frac{\sin2x\frac2{\sin2x}}2dx
+\sin2x\int\frac{\cos2x\frac2{\sin2x}}2dx\\
&=-x\cos2x+\frac12\sin2x\log|\sin2x|
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution using matrices.

The equation can be written
$$
\begin{pmatrix}y'\\y''\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-4&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}y\\y'\end{pmatrix}  + \begin{pmatrix}0\\\frac{1}{\sin 2x}\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Introducing $A = \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-4&0\end{pmatrix}$, $B(x) = \begin{pmatrix}0\\\frac{1}{\sin 2x}\end{pmatrix}$ and $Y=\begin{pmatrix}y\\y'\end{pmatrix}$,
the solution of this nice first order equation $Y'=AY+B(x)$ is given by

$$
Y(x) = \mathrm{e}^{(x-x_0)A}Y_0 + \int_{x_0}^x \mathrm{e}^{(x-t)A}B(t)\mathrm{d}t
$$
where $Y_0 = \begin{pmatrix}y_0\\y_0'\end{pmatrix}$ is the initial condition and the exponential of the matrix is given by $$\mathrm{e}^{xA} = \begin{pmatrix}\cos 2x&\frac{1}{2}\sin 2x\\-2\sin 2x&\cos 2x\end{pmatrix}.
$$

A straightforward and uninteresting computation leads to
$$
\boxed{
y(x) = \cos(2(x-x_0)) y_0 + \frac{1}{2}\sin(2(x-x_0))y_0' + (x_0-x)\cos(2x) + \frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)\ln\left|\frac{\sin(2x)}{\sin(2x_0)}\right|}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$y^{\prime\prime}+4y=\frac{2}{\sin(2x)}$$
$$y^{\prime\prime}{\sin(2x)}+4y{\sin(2x)}={2}$$
$$y^{\prime\prime}{\sin(2x)}\color{red}{+2y'\cos(2x)-2y'{\cos(2x)}}+4y{\sin(2x)}={2}$$
$$ (y^{\prime}{\sin(2x)})'-(2y{\cos(2x)})'={2}$$
After integration
$$ y^{\prime}{\sin(2x)}-2y{\cos(2x)}={2x}+C_1$$
$$ \left( \frac y {\sin(2x)}\right )'=\frac {{2x}+C_1}{\sin^2(2x)}$$
Integrate again:
$$  y(x)=C_2\sin(2x)+ {C_1}{\cos(2x)}+\frac 1 2 \sin(2x)\ln |\sin(2x)|-x\cos(2x)$$